# Stop Nginx from listening on all loopback IPv4 addresses EXCEPT 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, ip-address, nginx-reverse-proxy, loopback

On Ubuntu, Nginx apparently listens on all of the IPs in `127.0.0.0/8`. How can I disable listening on `127.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.2`–`127.255.255.255`? That is, the only IPv4 loopback address that I want Nginx to listen on is `127.0.0.1`. Answers to this question should ***not*** affect Nginx listening on any other IP addresses (e.g., the server's LAN and WAN addresses).

[Stop nginx listening on all IPs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1031438/stop-nginx-listening-on-all-ips) is a related question, but this question is specific to disabling Nginx on the loopback interfaces only without limiting it to a single listening IP.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the official documentation on the [`listen` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen)? Or the documentation on [How nginx processes a request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)?

> Syntax:   **listen** *address*[:*port*] [default_server] [ssl] [http2 | quic] [proxy_protocol] [setfib=*number*] [fastopen=*number*] [backlog=*number*] [rcvbuf=*size*] [sndbuf=*size*] [accept_filter=*filter*] [deferred] [bind] [ipv6only=on|off] [reuseport] [so_keepalive=on|off|[*keepidle*]:[*keepintvl*]:[*keepcnt*]];

So

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;     # loopback
    listen 192.168.1.100:80; # LAN
    listen 192.0.2.3:80;     # WAN
}
```

or

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1;     # loopback
    listen 192.168.1.100; # LAN
    listen 192.0.2.3;     # WAN
}
```

because

> If only *address* is given, the port 80 is used.

Comment: If I write `listen 127.0.0.1:80;` or `listen 127.0.0.1;`, then that will make my server inaccessible from other machines. As I wrote in my question, I'd just like to *disable* listening on some of the loopback addresses, not *enable* listening on one of them.

Comment: then `listen` on only the address**es** you want to listen on?